# rails docker app container not getting start

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-4, docker-compose, supervisord

I have docker version 17.12.1-ce and docker-compose version 1.17.1 when I run docker-compose up I get the following error.

```
app_1        | Error: The directory named as part of the path /app/tmp/supervisord.pid does not exist.
```

I'm very new to docker please let me know what I should run the same code is running on other machine with same versions of docker and docker-compose.

Comment: if your app is just one process (like normal rails app) supervisord is not needed you can start the app using rails directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problem with my database configuration I run the app outside the container and then started the container and it worked just publishing for others